# Django filters for related models for order_by max count

Tags: python, django

I know that count only can be applied for an IntegerField or FloatField but I've created a ForeignKey to another model which contains hitcounts. Now I need to filter results by max count from related model and I couldn't dot it.

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    default = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='default_category', null=True, blank=True)
    hits = models.ForeignKey(HitCount)

    objects = ProductManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-title", '-hits']
```

The idea is to access Hitcount field hits to count max value and sort list by max count. Below is Hitcount model installed as third party reusable app djagno-hitcount.

```
class HitCount(models.Model):
    hits = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_pk = models.PositiveIntegerField('object ID')
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_pk')

    objects = HitCountManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-hits',)
        get_latest_by = "modified"
        verbose_name = _("hit count")
        verbose_name_plural = _("hit counts")
        unique_together = ("content_type", "object_pk")
        db_table = "hitcount_hit_count"
```

I need to call products in multiple apps with different list and in my mainpage views I am trying to use filter option like below:

```
from django.db.models import Max, Sum, Count
product1 = Product.objects.all().annotate(hits=Count('-hits__hits'))[:6]
```

or

```
product1 = Product.objects.all().order_by('-hits__hits')[:6]
```

and with few different filter options. I couldn't make it work so advise would be appreciated.

Comment: I see you have imported `Max` too. So did you use it?

Comment: It says misuse of aggregate: Max() when I use Max. With Max I believe we cannot use "-hits" instead we have to call it "hits". So I changed Meta in Product models from -hits to hits, and also used as it is. With "-hits" it says there is no matching filed to "-hits" and provides options to select in error page where it show "hits". So I used hits but then error pops up. I just need to set order_by max hits count.

Comment: Okay so i have a doubt here. Going by what you have tried, you want a list of top 6 products sorted by hit count.? I'm I right? Coz i think misinterpreted your problem initially. So i thought i should ask you what exactly do you want.

Comment: If you want the former, that is, list of top 6 products sorted by hit count ( by top i mean max), then what error did you get in `product1 = Product.objects.all().order_by('-hits__hits')[:6]` ?

Comment: Thank you Ankush for your kidn help the problem is that it doesn't gives me any error otherwise I would had posted full traceback. It shows me 6 products in list and that's all. In Product model i changed ForeignKey to ManyToMany field by assuming its not establishing a connection to related model but in both cases no error popped up.

Comment: Firstly, it won't happen that using ForeignKey it won't establish connection, and using a ManyToMany it will. As far as I know, you don't need a `annotate` as you don't require any calculations. And you don't need an `aggregate` coz don't want a terminal or basically a single value for your query, like a `MAX` or `MIN` or `AVG` value. You want a list of top 6 Product objects sorted by their hit count value in descending order, for which i suppose `product1 = Product.objects.all().order_by('-hits__hits')[:6]` should have worked.
Are those 6 `Product` objects not  the ones with max hit count?

Comment: There are 50 products with max hits in db. You are right that M2M will establish a relation not with FK. But i've tried your solution before posting but this does not sort products with max count. You can see django-hitcount repo online to figure out solution for me. I appreciate your kind help for this problem.